# Resource manager class with basic dependency handling in java

Tags: java, object-oriented, generics

**Updates**: I kept the original code here, while performed some changes on my machine, including:

1. fixed the incorrect return documentation for `clear()`
2. made the closing functions recursive too (to be more clear and order-safe)
3. moved the static inner classes into separate files
4. extracted the API into an interface
5. use `.addSuppressed(e)` for handling more closing exceptions

---

This is a simple resource storage with basic dependency management. When we open a resource, its dependencies will be also opened (and vica versa when closing).

I post this here because the resulted code is surprisingly long (to me), and I also placed several `NOSONAR` flags because of the (necessarily) wildcarded result types.

I obfuscated the package name.

```java
package lorem.ipsum;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Storage for openable and closeable resources with basic dependency handling.
 * 
 * When opening a resource, its dependencies will also be opened.
 * When closing a resource, its dependants will also be closed.
 */
public class ResourceManager {

    private final String label;

    private final Map<Key<?>, Entry<?>> entries = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private final Map<Key<?>, Set<Key<?>>> dependants = new HashMap<>();


    /**
     * Creates a new empty resource manager
     */
    public ResourceManager() {
        this("Resources");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new empty resource manager with the specified label
     * 
     * @param label
     */
    public ResourceManager(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the storage label
     * 
     * @return The label
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * Registers a new resource under the specified key
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @param factory The resource factory
     * @param dependencies Optional dependencies
     * @throws CyclicDependencyException is dependency cycle is detected
     */
    public <T extends AutoCloseable> void register(
            Key<T> key,
            Factory<T> factory,
            Key<?>... dependencies) {
        register(key, factory, createAutoCloser(), Arrays.asList(dependencies));
    }

    /**
     * Registers a new resource under the specified key
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @param factory The resource factory
     * @param closer Custom closer code
     * @param dependencies Optional dependencies
     * @throws CyclicDependencyException is dependency cycle is detected
     */
    public <T> void register(
            Key<T> key,
            Factory<T> factory,
            Closer<T> closer,
            Key<?>... dependencies) {
        register(key, factory, closer, Arrays.asList(dependencies));
    }

    /**
     * Registers a new resource under the specified key
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @param factory The resource factory
     * @param dependencies Dependencies
     * @throws CyclicDependencyException is dependency cycle is detected
     */
    public <T extends AutoCloseable> void register(
            Key<T> key,
            Factory<T> factory,
            Collection<? extends Key<?>> dependencies) {
        register(key, factory, createAutoCloser(), dependencies);
    }

    /**
     * Registers a new resource under the specified key
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @param factory The resource factory
     * @param closer Custom closer code
     * @param dependencies Dependencies
     * @throws CyclicDependencyException is dependency cycle is detected
     */
    public synchronized <T> void register(
            Key<T> key,
            Factory<T> factory,
            Closer<T> closer,
            Collection<? extends Key<?>> dependencies) {
        if (entries.containsKey(key)) {
            throw new DuplicateKeyException(key);
        }
        checkCycle(key, dependencies);
        entries.put(key, new Entry<>(key, factory, closer, dependencies));
        for (Key<?> dependency : dependencies) {
            dependants.computeIfAbsent(dependency, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(key);
        }
    }

    private static <C extends AutoCloseable> Closer<C> createAutoCloser() {
        return (resourceManager, key, value) -> value.close();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if this manager is empty
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> if there are no resource, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return entries.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of resources in this manager
     * 
     * @return The number of resources
     */
    public synchronized int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the set of registered keys
     * 
     * @return The set of registered keys
     */
    public synchronized Set<Key<?>> keySet() { // NOSONAR
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(entries.keySet());
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the specified key is registered
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @return <code>true</code> if the key is registered, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public synchronized boolean containsKey(Key<?> key) {
        return entries.containsKey(key);
    }

    /**
     * Gets resource under the specified key.
     * 
     * Returns with null if <code>key</code> is not registered
     * or the resource is not open.
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @return The resource or <code>null</code>
     */
    public synchronized <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Entry<T> entry = (Entry<T>) entries.get(key);
        if (entry == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return entry.resource;
    }

    /**
     * Returns with open resource with the specified key.
     * 
     * Opens the resource and its dependencies if it is not open.
     * Does not return with <code>null</code>. Throws exception if <code>key</code> is missing.
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if <code>key</code> or any dependency is missing
     * @throws OpeningFailedException if opening of this resource or any dependency was failed
     * @return The open resource
     */
    public synchronized <T> T open(Key<T> key) {
        Entry<T> entry = getEntry(key);
        if (entry.resource != null) {
            return entry.resource;
        }
        for (Key<?> dependency : entry.dependecies) {
            open(dependency);
        }
        return entry.get();
    }

    /**
     * Closes resource under the specified key.
     * 
     * If <code>key</code> is missing, then exception will be thrown.
     * If resource is already open, no operation will be performed.
     * If closing was failed (because of this resource or any dependant),
     * throws an exception and stops closing,
     * so this close variant is non aggressive (see {@link #close(Key, boolean)}).
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if <code>key</code> is missing
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of this resource or any dependant was failed
     * @param key The key
     */
    public synchronized void close(Key<?> key) {
        close(key, false);
    }

    /**
     * Closes resource under the specified key.
     * 
     * If <code>key</code> is missing, then exception will be thrown.
     * If resource is already open, no operation will be performed.
     * If closing was failed (because of this resource or any dependant),
     * then throws an exception, and in aggressive mode does not stop and
     * tries to close each dependency (including this resource).
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if <code>key</code> is missing
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of this resource or any dependant was failed
     * @param key The key
     * @param aggressive Enables aggressive mode
     */
    public synchronized void close(Key<?> key, boolean aggressive) {
        closeInternal(key, aggressive);
    }

    /**
     * Closes all resources in this manager.
     * 
     * This is non aggressive (see {@link #close(Key, boolean)}).
     * 
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of any resource was failed
     */
    public synchronized void closeAll() {
        closeAll(false);
    }

    /**
     * Closes all resources in this manager.
     * 
     * This is possibly aggressive (see {@link #close(Key, boolean)}).
     * 
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of any resource was failed
     * @param aggressive Enables aggressive mode
     */
    public synchronized void closeAll(boolean aggressive) {
        if (aggressive) {
            closeAllInternalAggressive();
        } else {
            closeAllInternalNonAggressive();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void closeAllInternalNonAggressive() {
        for (Key<?> key : entries.keySet()) {
            closeInternal(key, false);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void closeAllInternalAggressive() {
        ClosingFailedException exception = null;
        for (Key<?> key : entries.keySet()) {
            try {
                closeInternal(key, true);
            } catch (ClosingFailedException e) {
                exception = e;
            }
        }
        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes and removes resource at the specified key.
     * 
     * Dependants will kept, so calling this method can leave this manager
     * in a non consistent state, in which you can register an alternative
     * dependency instead of this. For instant consistency use {@link #remove(Key, boolean)}.
     * See {@link #close(Key, boolean)}. This is non aggressive, 
     * and resource will be kept in case of a closing related exception.
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if <code>key</code> is missing
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of this resource or any dependant was failed
     * @return The resource removed from this key
     */
    public synchronized <T> T remove(Key<T> key) {
        return remove(key, false);
    }

    /**
     * Closes and removes resource at the specified key and possibly its dependencies.
     * 
     * See {@link #close(Key, boolean)}. This is non aggressive, 
     * and no resource will be removed in case of a closing related exception.
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @param removeDependants Remove dependants too or not
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if <code>key</code> is missing
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of this resource or any dependant was failed
     * @return The resource removed from this key
     */
    public synchronized <T> T remove(Key<T> key, boolean removeDependants) {
        T resource = getEntry(key).resource;
        List<Key<?>> allDependants = closeInternal(key, false);
        if (removeDependants) {
            for (Key<?> dependant : allDependants) {
                entries.remove(dependant);
                dependants.remove(dependant);
            }
        }
        entries.remove(key);
        dependants.remove(key);
        return resource;
    }

    private synchronized List<Key<?>> closeInternal(Key<?> key, boolean aggressive) { // NOSONAR
        if (aggressive) {
            return closeInternalAggressive(key);
        } else {
            return closeInternalNonAggressive(key);
        }
    }

    private synchronized List<Key<?>> closeInternalNonAggressive(Key<?> key) { // NOSONAR
        List<Key<?>> allDependants = getAllDependants(key);
        int countOfDependants = allDependants.size();
        for (int i = countOfDependants - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Key<?> dependantKey = allDependants.get(i);
            getEntry(dependantKey).close();
        }
        getEntry(key).close();
        return allDependants;
    }

    private synchronized List<Key<?>> closeInternalAggressive(Key<?> key) { // NOSONAR
        List<Key<?>> allDependants = getAllDependants(key);
        int countOfDependants = allDependants.size();
        ClosingFailedException exception = null;
        for (int i = countOfDependants - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Key<?> dependantKey = allDependants.get(i);
            try {
                getEntry(dependantKey).close();
            } catch (ClosingFailedException e) {
                exception = e;
            }

        }
        getEntry(key).close();
        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        }
        return allDependants;
    }

    /**
     * Closes and removes all resources.
     * 
     * See {@link #closeAll()}.
     * 
     * @throws ClosingFailedException if closing of any resource was failed
     * @return The resource removed from this key
     */
    public synchronized void clear() {
        closeAll();
        entries.clear();
        dependants.clear();
    }

    private Set<Key<?>> getDependants(Key<?> key) {
        Set<Key<?>> result = dependants.get(key);
        return result == null ? new HashSet<>() : result;
    }

    private List<Key<?>> getAllDependants(Key<?> key) {
        List<Key<?>> allDependants = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Key<?>> currentDependants = getDependants(key);
        while (!currentDependants.isEmpty()) {
            allDependants.addAll(currentDependants);
            Set<Key<?>> newDependants = new HashSet<>();
            for (Key<?> currentKey : currentDependants) {
                newDependants.addAll(getDependants(currentKey));
            }
            newDependants.removeAll(allDependants);
            currentDependants = newDependants;
        }
        return allDependants;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if resource under the specified key is registered and is open.
     * 
     * @param key The key
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if key is missing
     * @return <code>true</code> if the resource is open, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public synchronized boolean isOpen(Key<?> key) {
        return getEntry(key).resource != null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is any open resource
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> is any open resource found, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public synchronized boolean hasOpen() {
        for (Entry<?> entry : entries.values()) {
            if (entry.resource != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of open resources in this manager
     * 
     * @return The number of open resources
     */
    public synchronized int countOpen() {
        int result = 0;
        for (Entry<?> entry : entries.values()) {
            if (entry.resource != null) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the set of keys of open resources in this manager
     * 
     * @return The set of open keys
     */
    public synchronized Set<Key<?>> openKeySet() { // NOSONAR
        Set<Key<?>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Entry<?> entry : entries.values()) {
            if (entry.resource != null) {
                result.add(entry.key);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the set of closed of open resources in this manager
     * 
     * @return The set of closed keys
     */
    public synchronized Set<Key<?>> closedKeySet() { // NOSONAR
        Set<Key<?>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Entry<?> entry : entries.values()) {
            if (entry.resource == null) {
                result.add(entry.key);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private <T> Entry<T> getEntry(Key<T> key) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Entry<T> entry = (Entry<T>) entries.get(key);
        if (entry == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Key not found: %s", key));
        }
        return entry;
    }

    private void checkCycle(Key<?> key, Collection<? extends Key<?>> dependencies) {
        Set<Key<?>> currentDependencies = new HashSet<>(dependencies);
        Set<Key<?>> allDependencies = new HashSet<>(dependencies);
        while (!currentDependencies.isEmpty()) {
            Set<Key<?>> nextDependencies = new HashSet<>();
            for (Key<?> dependency : currentDependencies) {
                if (dependency.equals(key)) {
                    throw new CyclicDependencyException();
                }
                Entry<?> entry = entries.get(key);
                if (entry != null) {
                    nextDependencies.addAll(entry.dependecies);
                }
            }
            nextDependencies.removeAll(allDependencies);
            allDependencies.addAll(nextDependencies);
            currentDependencies = nextDependencies;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Key for resources to store under
     * 
     * @param <T> Resource type
     */
    public static class Key<T> implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private final String name;

        private final Class<T> resourceType;


        /**
         * Constructs a key.
         * 
         * You can store resources with this key with the specified type only.
         * You can use the same <code>name</code> multiple times with different <code>type</code>s.
         * 
         * @param name Name of this key
         * @param resourceType Resource type
         */
        public Key(String name, Class<T> resourceType) {
            this.name = name;
            this.resourceType = resourceType;
        }


        /**
         * Gets the key name
         * 
         * @return The name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the associated resource type
         * 
         * @return The resource type
         */
        public Class<T> getResourceType() {
            return resourceType;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if this key is equal to the given object.
         * 
         * If <code>obj</code> is not a {@link Key}, then returns with false.
         * Thwo key are equal, iff their names and types are both equal.
         * 
         * @return <code>true</code> if equals, <code>false</code> otherwise
         */
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }
            Key<?> otherKey = (Key<?>) obj;
            return name.equals(otherKey.name) && resourceType == otherKey.resourceType; 
        }

        /**
         * Generates hash code for this key
         * 
         * @return The hash code
         */
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (name.hashCode() * 31) + resourceType.hashCode();
        }

        /**
         * Generates string representation for this key.
         * 
         * Format of the string is: &lt;name&gt; ":" &lt;type&gt; .
         * 
         * @return The string representation
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s:%s", name, resourceType.getName());
        }

    }


    /**
     * Functional interface for resource factory lambdas
     *
     * @param <T> Resource type
     */
    public interface Factory<T> {

        public T create(ResourceManager resourceManager, Key<T> key) throws Exception; // NOSONAR

    }



    /**
     * Functional interface for custom resource closer lambdas
     *
     * @param <T> Resource type
     */
    public interface Closer<T> {

        public void close(ResourceManager resourceManager, Key<T> key, T value) throws Exception; // NOSONAR

    }


    /**
     * Exception, thrown when a duplicated key given
     */
    public static class DuplicateKeyException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private final Key<?> key;


        private DuplicateKeyException(Key<?> key) {
            super(String.format("Duplicate key: %s", key));
            this.key = key;
        }


        /**
         * Gets the key tried to duplicate
         * 
         * @return The key
         */
        public Key<?> getKey() { // NOSONAR
            return key;
        }

    }


    /**
     * Exception, thrown when cyclic dependencies detected
     */
    public static class CyclicDependencyException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private CyclicDependencyException() {
            super("Cyclic dependency detected");
        }

    }


    /**
     * Exception, thrown when opening of a resource failed
     */
    public static class OpeningFailedException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private final Key<?> key;


        private OpeningFailedException(Key<?> key, Exception e) {
            super(String.format("Opening failed: %s", key), e);
            this.key = key;
        }


        /**
         * Gets the key of the unopenable resource
         * 
         * @return The key
         */
        public Key<?> getKey() { // NOSONAR
            return key;
        }

    }


    /**
     * Exception thrown when closing of a resource failed
     */
    public static class ClosingFailedException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private final Key<?> key;


        public ClosingFailedException(Key<?> key, Exception e) {
            super(String.format("Closing failed: %s", key), e);
            this.key = key;
        }


        /**
         * Gets the key of the uncloseable resource
         * 
         * @return The key
         */
        public Key<?> getKey() { // NOSONAR
            return key;
        }

    }


    private class Entry<T> {

        final Key<T> key;

        final Factory<T> factory;

        final Closer<T> closer;

        final List<Key<?>> dependecies;

        T resource = null;


        Entry(
                Key<T> key,
                Factory<T> factory,
                Closer<T> closer,
                Collection<? extends Key<?>> dependecies) {
            this.key = key;
            this.factory = factory;
            this.closer = closer;
            this.dependecies = new ArrayList<>(dependecies);
        }


        T get() {
            if (resource == null) {
                try {
                    resource = factory.create(ResourceManager.this, key);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new OpeningFailedException(key, e);
                }
            }
            return resource;
        }

        void close() {
            if (resource != null) {
                try {
                    closer.close(ResourceManager.this, key, resource);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ClosingFailedException(key, e);
                }
                resource = null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And here are the tests:

````java
package lorem.ipsum;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ResourceManagerTest {

    @Test
    void testBasicsOfEmpty() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createEmptyResourceManager();

        String label = resourceManager.getLabel();

        assertThat(resourceManager.toString()).as("string").isEqualTo(label);
        assertThat(resourceManager).matches(r -> r.isEmpty(), "should be empty");
        assertThat(resourceManager.size()).as("size").isZero();
        assertThat(resourceManager.keySet()).as("keys").isEmpty();
        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key("foo"))).as("contains foo").isFalse();
        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isFalse();
        assertThat(resourceManager.countOpen()).as("open count").isZero();
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEmpty();
        assertThat(resourceManager.closedKeySet()).as("closed keys").isEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    void testBasicsOfFilled() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThat(resourceManager).matches(r -> !r.isEmpty(), "should not be empty");
        assertThat(resourceManager.size()).as("size").isEqualTo(10);
        assertThat(resourceManager.keySet()).as("keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "light", "camera", "cameraman", "shot", "movie",
                "fire", "cookbook", "chef", "cooking", "cookingshow"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key("foo"))).as("contains foo").isFalse();
        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key("light"))).as("contains foo").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isFalse();
        assertThat(resourceManager.countOpen()).as("open count").isZero();
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEmpty();
        assertThat(resourceManager.closedKeySet()).as("closed keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "light", "camera", "cameraman", "shot", "movie",
                "fire", "cookbook", "chef", "cooking", "cookingshow"));
    }

    @Test
    void testKeyDuplication() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.register(key("light"), this::create)).as("duplicate light")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.DuplicateKeyException.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testOpen() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        String label = resourceManager.getLabel();
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> lightKey = key("light");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> fireKey = key("fire");
        resourceManager.open(lightKey);

        assertThat(resourceManager.toString()).as("string").isEqualTo(label);
        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.countOpen()).as("open count").isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(keys("light"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.closedKeySet()).as("closed keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "camera", "cameraman", "shot", "movie",
                "fire", "cookbook", "chef", "cooking", "cookingshow"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.isOpen(lightKey)).as("light is open").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.isOpen(fireKey)).as("light is open").isFalse();
        assertThat(resourceManager.get(lightKey).isClosed()).as("light is off").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testOpenComplex1() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        resourceManager.open(key("movie"));

        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "light", "camera", "cameraman", "shot", "movie"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.closedKeySet()).as("closed keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "fire", "cookbook", "chef", "cooking", "cookingshow"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.countOpen()).as("open count").isEqualTo(5);
    }

    @Test
    void testOpenComplex2() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        resourceManager.open(key("cookingshow"));

        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("openKeys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "light", "camera", "cameraman", "shot",
                "fire", "cookbook", "chef", "cooking", "cookingshow"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.closedKeySet()).as("closed keys").isEqualTo(keys("movie"));
        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.countOpen()).as("open count").isEqualTo(9);
    }

    @Test
    void testOpenNonExisting() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.open(key("foo"))).as("openNonExisting")
                .isInstanceOf(NoSuchElementException.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testOpeningOrder() {
        List<ResourceManager.Key<?>> openingOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager(
                key -> openingOrder.add(key), key -> {});

        resourceManager.open(key("movie"));

        assertThat(openingOrder)
                .containsSubsequence(key("shot"), key("movie"))
                .containsSubsequence(key("light"), key("shot"))
                .containsSubsequence(key("camera"), key("shot"))
                .containsSubsequence(key("cameraman"), key("shot"));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetUnopened() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThat(resourceManager.get(key("light"))).as("light").isNull();
    }

    @Test
    void testGetOpened() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("light");
        resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThat(resourceManager.get(key)).as("light").isInstanceOf(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetNonExisting() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThat(resourceManager.get(key("foo"))).as("light").isNull();
    }

    @Test
    void testOpenWithDirectException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("unopenable");
        resourceManager.register(key, this::createUnopenable);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.open(key)).as("openingException")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.OpeningFailedException.class)
                .extracting(e -> ((ResourceManager.OpeningFailedException) e).getKey()).as("failedKey")
                .isEqualTo(key);
    }

    @Test
    void testOpenWithDependencyException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependencyKey = key("unopenable");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("dependantOfUnopenable");
        resourceManager.register(dependencyKey, this::createUnopenable);
        resourceManager.register(key, this::create, dependencyKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.open(key)).as("openingException")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.OpeningFailedException.class)
                .extracting(e -> ((ResourceManager.OpeningFailedException) e).getKey()).as("failedKey")
                .isEqualTo(dependencyKey);
    }

    @Test
    void testSingleOpenAndClose() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("light");
        TestResource resource = resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThat(!resource.isClosed()).as("really opened").isTrue();

        resourceManager.close(key);

        assertThat(resource.isClosed()).as("really closed").isTrue();

        assertThat(resourceManager.hasOpen()).as("has open").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testComplexOpenAndSingleClose() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<?> key = key("movie");
        resourceManager.open(key);
        resourceManager.close(key);

        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "light", "camera", "cameraman", "shot"));
        assertThat(!resourceManager.get(key("light")).isClosed()).as("light is on").isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testComplexOpenAndClose() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<?> movieKey = key("movie");
        ResourceManager.Key<?> lightKey = key("light");
        resourceManager.open(movieKey);
        resourceManager.close(lightKey);

        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(keys(
                "camera", "cameraman"));
    }

    @Test
    void testClosingOrder() {
        List<ResourceManager.Key<?>> closingOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager(
                key -> {}, key -> closingOrder.add(key));

        resourceManager.open(key("cookingshow"));

        resourceManager.close(key("cooking"));
        resourceManager.close(key("camera"));

        assertThat(closingOrder).isEqualTo(keyList("cookingshow", "cooking", "shot", "camera"));
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseAllOnEmptyWithoutException() {
        createEmptyResourceManager().closeAll();
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseNonExisting() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.close(key("foo"))).as("closeNonExisting")
                .isInstanceOf(NoSuchElementException.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseWithDirectException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("uncloseable");
        resourceManager.register(key, this::createUncloseable);
        resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.close(key)).as("closingException")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(e -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) e).getKey()).as("failedKey")
                .isEqualTo(key);
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseWithDependantException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependencyKey = key("dependency");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> uncloseableKey = key("uncloseable");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> leafDependantKey = key("leafDependant");
        resourceManager.register(dependencyKey, this::create);
        resourceManager.register(uncloseableKey, this::createUncloseable, dependencyKey);
        resourceManager.register(leafDependantKey, this::create, uncloseableKey);
        resourceManager.open(leafDependantKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.close(dependencyKey)).as("closingException")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(e -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) e).getKey()).as("failedKey")
                .isEqualTo(uncloseableKey);
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(dependencyKey, uncloseableKey)));
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseAggressiveWithException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependencyKey = key("dependency");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> uncloseableKey = key("uncloseable");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> leafDependantKey = key("leafDependant");
        resourceManager.register(dependencyKey, this::create);
        resourceManager.register(uncloseableKey, this::createUncloseable, dependencyKey);
        resourceManager.register(leafDependantKey, this::create, uncloseableKey);
        resourceManager.open(leafDependantKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.close(dependencyKey, true)).as("closingException")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(e -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) e).getKey()).as("failedKey")
                .isEqualTo(uncloseableKey);
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(uncloseableKey)));
    }

    @Test
    void testRemove() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("light");
        resourceManager.remove(key);

        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key)).as("contains light").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testRemoveOpen() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("light");
        TestResource resource = resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThat(!resource.isClosed()).as("light is really open").isTrue();

        resourceManager.remove(key);

        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key)).as("contains light").isFalse();
        assertThat(resource.isClosed()).as("light is really closed").isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testRemoveWithException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("uncloseable");
        resourceManager.register(key, this::createUncloseable);

        resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.remove(key)).as("closing failed while removing")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class);

        assertThat(resourceManager.containsKey(key)).as("contains uncloseable").isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testRemoveWithDependantException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependencyKey = key("dependency");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> uncloseableKey = key("uncloseable");
        resourceManager.register(dependencyKey, this::create);
        resourceManager.register(uncloseableKey, this::createUncloseable, dependencyKey);

        resourceManager.open(uncloseableKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.remove(dependencyKey)).as("closing failed while removing")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(exception -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) exception).getKey())
                .as("uncloseable key").isEqualTo(uncloseableKey);
        assertThat(resourceManager.get(dependencyKey).isClosed()).as("dependency is closed").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseAll() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> testKey = key("shot");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependantKey = key("movie");
        resourceManager.open(dependantKey);

        assertThat(resourceManager.isOpen(testKey)).as("shot is open before").isTrue();

        resourceManager.closeAll();

        assertThat(resourceManager.isOpen(testKey)).as("shot is open after").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseAllWithException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> uncloseableKey = key("uncloseable");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependantKey = key("dependant");
        resourceManager.register(uncloseableKey, this::createUncloseable, key("movie"));
        resourceManager.register(dependantKey, this::create, key("uncloseable"));

        resourceManager.open(dependantKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.closeAll()).as("close all exception")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(exception -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) exception).getKey())
                .as("uncloseable key").isEqualTo(uncloseableKey);
        assertThat(resourceManager.get(key("light")).isClosed()).as("light is off").isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testCloseAllAggressiveWithException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> uncloseableKey = key("uncloseable");
        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> dependantKey = key("dependant");
        resourceManager.register(uncloseableKey, this::createUncloseable, key("movie"));
        resourceManager.register(dependantKey, this::create, key("uncloseable"));

        resourceManager.open(dependantKey);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.closeAll(true)).as("closing all exception")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(exception -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) exception).getKey())
                .as("uncloseable key").isEqualTo(uncloseableKey);
        assertThat(resourceManager.openKeySet()).as("open keys").isEqualTo(keys("uncloseable"));
    }

    @Test
    void testClear() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        resourceManager.clear();

        assertThat(resourceManager.isEmpty()).as("manager is empty").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.keySet()).as("keys").isEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    void testClearWithOpen() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> lightKey = key("light");
        TestResource light = resourceManager.open(lightKey);
        resourceManager.open(key("light"));
        resourceManager.clear();

        assertThat(resourceManager.isEmpty()).as("manager is empty").isTrue();
        assertThat(resourceManager.keySet()).as("keys").isEmpty();
        assertThat(light.isClosed()).as("light is off").isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testClearWithException() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = createFilledResourceManager();

        ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key = key("uncloseable");
        resourceManager.register(key, this::createUncloseable);
        resourceManager.open(key);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> resourceManager.clear()).as("clearing exception")
                .isInstanceOf(ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException.class)
                .extracting(exception -> ((ResourceManager.ClosingFailedException) exception).getKey())
                .as("uncloseable key").isEqualTo(key);
        assertThat(resourceManager.size()).as("size: all should be kept").isEqualTo(11);
    }

    private ResourceManager createEmptyResourceManager() {
        return new ResourceManager("No resources");
    }

    private ResourceManager createFilledResourceManager() {
        return createFilledResourceManager(key -> {}, key -> {});
    }

    private ResourceManager createFilledResourceManager(
            Consumer<ResourceManager.Key<?>> onOpen, Consumer<ResourceManager.Key<?>> onClose) {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
        ResourceManager.Factory<TestResource> factory = (manager, key) -> {
            onOpen.accept(key);
            return this.create();
        };
        ResourceManager.Closer<TestResource> closer = (manager, key, value) -> {
            onClose.accept(key);
            value.close();
        };
        resourceManager.register(key("light"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("camera"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("cameraman"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("shot"), factory, closer, keys("light", "camera", "cameraman"));
        resourceManager.register(key("movie"), factory, closer, keys("shot"));
        resourceManager.register(key("fire"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("cookbook"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("chef"), factory, closer);
        resourceManager.register(key("cooking"), factory, closer, keys("light", "fire", "cookbook", "chef"));
        resourceManager.register(key("cookingshow"), factory, closer, keys("cooking", "shot"));
        return resourceManager;
    }

    private Set<ResourceManager.Key<TestResource>> keys(String... names) {
        Set<ResourceManager.Key<TestResource>> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (String name : names) {
            result.add(key(name));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<ResourceManager.Key<TestResource>> keyList(String... names) {
        List<ResourceManager.Key<TestResource>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : names) {
            result.add(key(name));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key(String name) {
        return new ResourceManager.Key<>(name, TestResource.class);
    }

    private TestResource create(
            ResourceManager resourceManager, ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key) {
        return create();
    }

    private TestResource create() {
        return new TestResource();
    }

    private TestResource createUnopenable(
            ResourceManager resourceManager, ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key) {
        return createUnopenable();
    }

    private TestResource createUnopenable() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is unopenable!");
    }

    private TestResource createUncloseable(
            ResourceManager resourceManager, ResourceManager.Key<TestResource> key) {
        return createUncloseable();
    }

    private TestResource createUncloseable() {
        return new TestResource(true);
    }


    static class TestResource implements Closeable {

        private final boolean uncloseable;

        private boolean closed = false;


        TestResource() {
            this(false);
        }

        TestResource(boolean uncloseable) {
            this.uncloseable = uncloseable;
        }


        @Override
        public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
            if (uncloseable) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("I am uncloseable!");
            }
            closed = true;
        }

        public boolean isClosed() {
            return closed;
        }

    }

}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a few things briefly scanning your code. I'de be happy to share.

### Exception State

Note the below snippet.

```java
ClosingFailedException exception = null;
for (Key<?> key : entries.keySet()) {
    try {
        closeInternal(key, true);
    } catch (ClosingFailedException e) {
        exception = e;
    }
}
if (exception != null) {
    throw exception;
}
```

I understand that you want to continue closing resources even if a resource failed to close, but currently as is, only the last failing resource to close will be thrown. It is possible that multiple resources could fail to close. Maybe it would be a good idea to maintain all closure failures, not just the last.

Also, the `CyclicDependencyException` could probably contain more information detailing which dependencies are cyclic. The current message is not very helpful to a consumer.

### Nested Classes

I would definitely pull the exceptions and interfaces out side of this implementation. Especially if you decide to make use of more abstractions, such as a `ResourceManager` interface. This implementation will no longer be the only class having a dependency on all your cool classes. Also, might be a good idea to give your interfaces more descriptive names, especially if they become standalone files.

### Consistency

Just to keep things consistent, the `Entry` class should have explicit access modifiers on fields, methods and constructors.

Comment: Only the last exception thrown: Hm, this bothers me too, but this is a general practice ([see this, for example](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/f08138d67868c9d7783f38af1d1b46fbb129238f/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/rest/RestService.java#L312)). Probably I should create CompoundClosingFailedException.

Comment: Entry class should have explicit access modifiers: My convention is to not use modifiers in private inner classes. This is the result of experimentation of long years. What are the arguments against this?

Comment: @DávidHorváth In regards to access modifiers, the best argument I can muster is when you override some superclass method, e.g toString(). It MUST be explicitly denoted public. Could look strange having access modifiers on somethings and not others, might as well explicitly state all modifiers. Obviously not the case here but definitely worth the discussion.